# Mystified about bad performance of MVC3, EF4.1 against SQL Azure on a Cloud Service?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, azure-web-roles

I have a web application which uses:

```
MVC3, Razor, C#, EF4.1, .NET4, MSSQL2008(local), SQL Azure(Cloud)
```

It reads data from DB, merges it and create an XHTML document.

1. When run locally(IIS Express/VS2012/Win7), it is fine.
2. When run locally in Emulator, also fine.
3. When run in WAWS, very speedy.

I am running .NET 4.0 in the cloud service, WAWS runs .NET4.5, this could be significant???

I have seen reference to compiled EF being great in performance. How do I compile my EF? I have a seperate EF Model Project for my DB access code which is compiled as a DLL into my Web Application bin folder.

EF performance issue, See:[EF Performance Article](http://www.outofmemory.co.uk/entity-framework-5-dramatically-faster-in-net-4-5/)

I have run the profiler in sample mode on my cloud service, and the LINQ/Entity lines seem to be the "Hot" commands, so it is EF related.

I would appreciate your comment on this please.

Thanks in advance.

P.s Now off to recompile my app in .NET4.5, and redeploy.

EDIT

Just redeployed using osFamily="4" and .Net4.5 and processing time reduced from 30 secs to 1 secs !!!!! Amazing. In runtime after deployment was still about 30 secs.

EDIT2

After change to .NET4.5 I got lots of "invalid Access to memory location" errors when invoking the full emulator. Not sure if this is to do with me running VS2012 or WIn7 with osFamily="4" in the emulator. see: [Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/10/31/compute-emulator-invalid-access-to-memory-location.aspx)

Comment: Not sure what the question is. But without any code, this is a shot in the dark. This could be due to .net4.5 having a query cache for LinqToEF compilation. Linq to EF needs to at some point convert your Linq statements into SQL. That is a non-trival task that is quite slow. In .net 4.5 there is automagic cache on this.

Comment: Hi Aron, Thanks for the comment. This must be something to do with it, since the redeployment in .NET4.5 has had a massive impact. Also WAWS uses .NET4.5 which is what got me thinking about why it runs the EF code so quickly.

Comment: From my experience, it seems that if you are deploying a MVC/EF application into a Cloud Service, then you really need to try and port into .NET4.5.